# Simplifying $\sum_{i=0}^{\log n} \frac{n}{\log\left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)}$

Tags: summation, algorithms, computational-complexity

> $$\sum_{i=0}^{\log n} \frac{n}{\log\left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)}$$

I'm having trouble seeing how this summation simplifies.

It seems it would be something like:

$$\frac{n}{\log(n)} + \frac{n}{\log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)} + \frac{n}{\log\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)} + \frac{n}{\log\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)} + \cdots +\frac{n}{\log\left(\frac{n}{2^{\log(n)}}\right)}$$

Somehow this sum $\in O(n\log(\log n))$, and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: The last term in the last equation is incorrect. What is the base of the logarithm?

Comment: @metamorphy base 2

Comment: If $n$ is a power of $2$, say $n=2^k$, the final term in the sum, with $i=\log_2(2^k)=k$, will be $2^k/\log_2(2^k/2^k)=2^k/\log_2(1)=2^k/0$, which is undefined.

Comment: With the remark on division by zero being fixed (say, by changing the upper limit to $\lfloor\log(n-1)\rfloor$), this boils down to approximation (by sums) of $\int_0^{a_n}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-x}$ with $a_n=\frac{\lfloor\log(n-1)\rfloor}{\log n}$.